# audio.currentTime creating javascript error

Tags: jquery, html

My javascript doesn't seem to want to specify the currentTime of my audio element, and I don't see this question asked anywhere else. audio.currentTime = 0; is producing DOM Exception 11:

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
    var audio = null ;
    audio = document.createElement ( 'audio' ) ;
    audio.src = 'stopped.m4a' ;
    audio.currentTime = 0 ;
} ) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`audio` is not defined at the time of use.

Comment: I still have the same error if I define audio specificall:'  var audio = null ;
  audio = document.createElement ( 'audio' ) ;
  audio.src = 'stopped.m4a' ;
  audio.currentTime = 0 ;'